# Pycharm Jupiter notebook does not see virtual environment packages

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I have a virtualenv in ~/tensorflow, and I can set a project with a .py file in Pycharm to use that virtualenv's python (by changing the project interpreter). Things work that way. However, I cannot get a Jupyter notebook, in the same project, to see the virtualenv's packages. It seems as if it's using a different python just for the notebook.

The server that the notebook is connected to is started in the same virtualenv. Web client does work fine with the same jupyter server too.

My guess is that Pycharm's connection to Jupyter server gets established somehow using a different kernel, but I have no idea why or how to change it.

Comment: Same problem here. I think I have identified the problem, the kernel running is the one linked to the interpreter of the virtual env in which jupyter is installed. Despite that the interpreter selected is the one from the project I want to run, as mentionned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902721/how-to-specify-python3-kernel-in-jupyter-in-pycharm

Comment: I have the same understanding of the issue. Does anyone have a clue how to get Jupyter to use the right venv?

Answer (score 1):

jupyter notebook doesn't use the virtual envirnonment's python distribution unless you specify it directly on the jupyter kernel.

in fact, if you run a jupyter notebook after activating a venv by a command like this `./venv/bin/python -m jupyter notebook`, just your notebook cells which contains terminal commands (cells which starts with `!`) run in the virtual environment.

you can use available jupyter kernels or make a new one. to see available kernels use `jupyter kernelspec list` command to find their path. for making a new kernel, use `ipython kernel install --user --name=venv` in the terminal.

then you should consider a kernel to change its python distribution path to which it is used in the virtual environment. so use `jupyter kernelspec list` to find the path of your desired kernel. at this path, you should see `kernel.json` file which contains :

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/bin/python3",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "venv",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

you should specify the first member of `argv` in this file to the path of the python distribution used in your virtual environment.

to find the python used in the virtual environemnt, first activate your venv, then prompt `which python3` in the terminal to see the python path which is used in the venv.

after configuring a kernel to use a python distribution in the venv, you should run jupyter notebook and choose the right kernel from top menus.

*note*

*you can delete extra kernels via `jupyter kernelspec uninstall venv`*

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had multiple kernels, and PyCharm launches the default kernel. One approach might be to set up PyCharm to specify the kernel of choice to start up, I didn't investigate how to do that. I simply changed the default kernel in Jupyter and this worked for me (I have a virtualenv for tensorflow). `c.MultiKernelManager.default_kernel_name = 'tensorflow'`.